# twitter_update_list script for fully customizable HTML Twitter feed not supported anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

It seems Twitter have updated their API, and the common script for spitting out the list and styling it up with CSS no longer works... Does anyone know of any other alternatives?:

The HTML:

```
<ul id="twitter_update_list">
        </ul>
```

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/iputmytwitterusernamehere.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See API changes here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

This now will require a specific authentication, something that wasn't needed before in version 1.0 of the API.

Comment: So how do I go about authenticating the feed?

Comment: Follow the API docs, see here - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authenticate

Answer (score 1):

Mine was broken too... here's one that works

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/youraccountname.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how it should be done: you have to put your username in the screen_name parameter. [Source here](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=twitterCallback2&screen_name=HEREISWHEREYOURUSERNAMESHOULDBE&count=6&include_rts=true).